# How to Store Changes in a Repo

Tags: git, github

Git newbie here. I am building a staging environment to mirror the production environment of SaaS web application. To do that, I had to make a lot of changes on the staging web server, which mainly consisted of modifying some of our scripts that we use to make our application run.

A colleague created a repo for me so I can store these modified staging scripts there.

**How do I do that?**

On the web server, in the directory where all the changes were made, I see this if I run 'git remote -v':

```
CompanyName https://abeecfad5a63849c4b53f6a9038932c3d80b52c8:x-oauth-basic@github.com/CompanyName/Hosted-Scripts.git (fetch)
CompanyName https://abeecfad5a63849c4b53f6a9038932c3d80b52c8:x-oauth-basic@github.com/CompanyName/Hosted-Scripts.git (push)
```

If I do a 'git status', I see that I am on 'branch master' and I see the scripts that I modified.

In the past, when making code changes (on my local machine), this what I have done: fork the company's repo to my personal github, download the code, make changes, commit and push any changes to my personal github (i.e. origin) and then make a PR for these changes to be reviewed and merged (my personal github is my master, and the company's github is my upstream when I do 'git remove -v'). But I am not sure how to do the same from this staging server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the first place don't just download from git. Use "git clone" to get a clone from the your repo which you have forked from company's repo.

And your upstream is your company's reop, as a good practice you have to get fetch from the upstream and merge it before you do any changers to your repo.

Then you do the changers to your code and commit it to your fork. Then make a PR to company's repo. As a good practice you have to make only one commit per PR some companies want that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I agree git clone should be used.

So how do I store the changes in this example above? Are you saying that I have to set up that repo as my upstream first? Would you mind listing the steps (or a general outline of the steps) that I have to take? Thanks again!

Comment: I think you didn't add the upstream here because if you add upstream and run the command git remote -v it will show four lines of codes two for origin and other two for upstream